# Implementing and calling JFrame/ActionListener class from main

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener

I'm trying to get my program to launch a gui that gathers information before the actual programs starts. In main I try to call the JFrame which should then run until the start button is pressed and then the main program should launch. Everything seems to be correct except for the base class of the initializeLauncher. Thanks!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class InitializeLauncher implements ActionListener {

    InitializeLauncher() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("launcherClient");

        Container c = frame.getContentPane();
        Dimension d = new Dimension(700,400);
        c.setPreferredSize(d);

        JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
        JPanel pane = new JPanel();

        startButton.addActionListener(this);

        pane.add(startButton);
        frame.add(pane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void buttonClicked(ActionEvent e)
    {
        ApplicationDeploy displayExample = new ApplicationDeploy();
        displayExample.initializeGameClient();
    }
}
```

...and then in main I call this:

```
InitializeLauncher launcher = new InitializeLauncher();
launcher.InitializeLauncher();
```

Comment: You should start your class names with a capital letter. Also, I think you have a superfluous inheritance - I see no reason why your class should extend JFrame in this case.

Comment: So, what's the question? What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: I fixed the stuff you said kviiri, thanks. The problem is that class InitializeLauncher throws an error "The type InitializeLauncher must implement the inherited abstract method ActionListener.actionPerformed(ActionEvent)" but if I make it abstract, can't I not call it from main anymore?                    Edit: If I make the class abstract then I cant make a version of it from main anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By making your class abstract, you're fixing the wrong thing. Instead you should give your class the missing method, `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {...}`

The basic rule here is, if you state that your class is going to implement an interface, here the ActionListener interface, then the class **must** implement all of the methods of the interface.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   // ... your code that should occur when the button is pressed goes here
}
```

Note that your `buttonClicked(...)` method will do nothing useful for you. Likely you'll want to get rid of that method and put its code into the actionPerformed method.

As an aside, I often use a JOptionPane for the functionality that you're using a JFrame for.

Comment: Perfect, thanks, didn't realize I named the action event wrong.